# Proper usage of the extendability of "this" in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We could briefly describe that **this.props** is data flow from parent component and **this.state** is for keeping the current state of the component, and the mechanism we massively depend when we develop in React is re-rendering after **setState()**.

If my understanding of the usage of these two are not wrong,
except holding function object, is it proper to utilize the extendability of **this** to hold some values considered as global variables?

For example, if I want to make 'swipe' manner available on my component, I may could do something like:

```
class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            movement: 0,
            touchStartX: 0,
            prevTouchX: 0,
            beingTouched: false
        };  
        this.handleTouchStart = this.handleTouchStart.bind(this);
        this.handleTouchMove = this.handleTouchMove.bind(this);
        this.handleTouchEnd = this.handleTouchEnd.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleTouchStart(e) {
        this.setState({
            touchStartX: e.targetTouches[0].clientX,
            beingTouched: true
        });
    }
    
    handleTouchMove(e) {
        if (this.state.beingTouched) {
            let deltaX = e.targetTouches[0].clientX - this.state.touchStartX;
            this.setState({
                movement: deltaX,
                prevTouchX: e.targetTouches[0].clientX
            });
        }
    }
    handleTouchEnd(e) {
        // handle the sliding and set state touchStartX and beingTouched to 0 and false.
    }
    render() {
        return (<div className = 'sliderBox' 
                 onTouchStart = {e => this.handleTouchStart(e)}  
                 onTouchMove = {e => this.handleTouchMove(e)}  
                 onTouchEnd = {e => this.handleTouchEnd(e)}></div>);
    }
}
export default Slider;
```

This is a part of my built application, it just works well. But I still wonder if it's a good way to use **state** property.
Or it's just OK to do something like:

```
class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.movement = 0;
        this.touchStartX = 0;
        this.prevTouchX = 0;
        this.beingTouched = false;

        this.handleTouchStart = this.handleTouchStart.bind(this);
        this.handleTouchMove = this.handleTouchMove.bind(this);
        this.handleTouchEnd = this.handleTouchEnd.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleTouchStart(e) {
        this.touchStartX = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
        this.beingTouched = true;
    }
    
    handleTouchMove(e) {
        if (this.beingTouched) {
            let deltaX = e.targetTouches[0].clientX - this.state.touchStartX;
            this.movement = deltaX;
            this.prevTouchX = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
        }
    }
    handleTouchEnd(e) {
        // handle the sliding and set state touchStartX and beingTouched to 0 and false.
    }
    render() {
        return (<div className = 'sliderBox' 
                 onTouchStart = {e => this.handleTouchStart(e)}  
                 onTouchMove = {e => this.handleTouchMove(e)}  
                 onTouchEnd = {e => this.handleTouchEnd(e)}></div>);
    }
}
export default Slider;
```

But it seems that the utilization of the extendability of **this** above is rarely seen?

Sorry if my question is meaningless, I just wonder if is there any spirit or principle to utilize the extendability of **this**? Props and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that extendability of `this` in the react component is a normal practice, I've seen it being used in almost every more or less complex React project I have worked on.

As for deciding where to put the data in the state or on the component itself, I usually ask myself a question: does the component need to react to the change of those properties? If yes, they are going in the state, if not - on the component.

In your case, since you are using those properties only in event handlers and don't really need the component to re-render every time they change, I'd say optimal would be to utilise `this`, as you do.

On the other hand, if you want to use `beingTouched` property in the render method, for example, to change the background color of the component when it's touched than you need to put it in the state, otherwise the component would not react as expected, because it will be unaware that the property has changed.

Comment: Gleb Kost, really appreciate your answer, it seems it is just clear enough! Sorry that just waiting for more disscusions, I may accept your answer later!

Comment: absolutely! I'd also love to see other opinions on that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can attach variables directly to the component's `this`. It's proper in your use case.

In [React's Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) itself, in the state and lifecycle section, it gives an example of storing a timer id directly in `this`:

> ```
> componentDidMount() {
>   this.timerID = setInterval(
>     () => this.tick(),
>     1000
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> Note how we save the timer ID right on `this`.
>
> While `this.props` is set up by React itself and `this.state` has a special meaning, you are free to add additional fields to the class manually if you need to store something that is not used for the visual output.
>
> If you don’t use something in `render()`, it shouldn’t be in the state.
>
> We will tear down the timer in the `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle hook:
>
> ```
> componentWillUnmount() {
>   clearInterval(this.timerID);
> }
> ```

And as of [Gleb Kost's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48282628/1064325), I agree that it's a normal practice.

You've nailed it. If it doesn't make sense to be in props, neither in state, feel free to attach it directly to `this`, if it also makes sense.

Comment: very appreciate your answer and example from official site too! I think things just be more certain for me now! Sorry that I need to accept Gleb's answer because it comes first! Thanks again.

Comment: @Carr I've edited my answer to also include React's explanation on the subject. I'm glad it helped :)